# Ionic IonAlert trigger gives an error even though I just coppied it from the docs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-react

I copied this section of code in ionic react from https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert
and put it in the Home.tsx file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { IonAlert, IonButton } from '@ionic/react';

function Example() {
  return (
    <>
      <IonButton id="present-alert">Click Me</IonButton>
      <IonAlert
        trigger="present-alert"
        header="Alert"
        subHeader="Important message"
        message="This is an alert!"
        buttons={['OK']}
      ></IonAlert>
    </>
  );
}
export default Example;
```

I didn't change any of the code, but for some reason, it gave me this error:

> Type '{ trigger: string; header: string; subHeader: string; message:
> string; buttons: string[]; }' is not assignable to type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & AlertOptions & ReactControllerProps & {
> forwardedRef?: MutableRefObject<HTMLIonAlertElement | null> |
> ((instance: HTMLIonAlertElement | null) => void) | null | undefined; }
> & RefAttributes<...>'.   Property 'trigger' does not exist on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & AlertOptions & ReactCon

I am really new to this and I don't know why it won't let me run this. Thank you for any help

I expected it to pop open an alert, but it didn't. I tried to look up this error, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: How did you import the component?  What version of Ionic, and what version of React?  When do you get the error, when using the ionic CLI?